# How to set nested record using "set()"?

Tags: extjs

I'm facing problem in setting my record value.

I have nested record inside store like this :

```
- data
act_reading // I can set value of this record using -> record.set('act_reading', 'dsds');
adj_reading
act_reading_nested
    - data
        arr_act_colour // How can I set this record?
        arr_act_rating // How can I set this record?
        arr_act_ferrous // How can I set this record?
    idrectype1 // How can I set this record?
adj_reading_nested
    - data
        arr_adj_colour
        arr_adj_rating
        arr_adj_ferrous
    idrectype2
```

How can I set idrectype1 value inside act_reading_nested?

I also have to do the same thing for arr_act_colour, arr_act_rating, & arr_act_ferrous.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `record` is variable holding reference to your recrd, wouldn't that work?

```
record.get('act_reading_nested').set('arr_act_colour','value');
record.get('act_reading_nested').idrectype1 = 'something';
```

Yes it would. Just checked.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with current implementation of the Store you can not :( I'm facing with such kind issue too, when I'd like to edit a non-plain Store in the GridPanel. see http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119573-Event-beforeedit-in-EditableGridPanel&highlight=afteredit

I did not check it myself (rather found a hack workaround), but more clean way is to fix it with your own Store implementation using of Ext.override(Ext.Store, { ...}) facility.
See how I did it for 'standard' HttpProxy implementation.

```
Ext.override (Ext.data.HttpProxy, {
    buildUrl : function (action, record) {
        var ret = '';
        if (window.location.pathname != '/') {
            ret = window.location.pathname;
        };
        return ret + Ext.data.HttpProxy.superclass.buildUrl.call(this, action, record);
    }
});
```

It requires a bit deep Extjs internal knowledge though.

Comment: Why would that have enything to do with a store?